# Mongodb $lookup query using PHP driver not working

Tags: php, mongodb

> I want to get data from two collections where there is a common field
>   between this two collections.I am giving both queries for Mongo and
>   PHP. My PHP version is PHP 5.6.31-1~ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli)
>   My mongo db query for between two collections:

```
db.dental_refset.aggregate(
[
    {   $lookup:
        {
            from:"v20170731",
            localField:"referencedComponentId",
            foreignField:"conceptId",
            as:"joinedData"
        }
    }

])
```

I am ding this in php and my code is below:

```
error_reporting(1); 
require 'driver/vendor/autoload.php'; 
$client = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://192.168.2.95:27017");
$collection = $client->selectDatabase('en-edition')->selectCollection("dental_refset");
$ops = array(
    array(
        "$lookup" => array(
            "from" => "v20170731",
            "localField" => "referencedComponentId",
            "foreignField" => "conceptId",
            "as" => "user_docs"
        )
    )
);
$results = $collection->aggregate($ops);
print_r($collection);
```

> But error occurs. Error has given below:
>
> Uncaught MongoDB\Driver\Exception\RuntimeException: Invalid filter: empty
>   key in
>   /var/www/html/mednxtMod/mednxt/driver/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Operation/Aggregate.php:223\nStack
>   trace:\n#0
>   /var/www/html/mednxtMod/mednxt/driver/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Operation/Aggregate.php(223):
>   MongoDB\Driver\Server->executeCommand('en-edition',
>   Object(MongoDB\Driver\Command),
>   Object(MongoDB\Driver\ReadPreference))\n#1
>   /var/www/html/mednxtMod/mednxt/driver/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Collection.php(215):
>   MongoDB\Operation\Aggregate->execute(Object(MongoDB\Driver\Server))\n#2
>   /var/www/html/mednxtMod/mednxt/error.php(19):
>   MongoDB\Collection->aggregate(Array)\n#3 {main}\n  thrown in
>   /var/www/html/mednxtMod/mednxt/driver/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Operation/Aggregate.php
>   on line 223Uncaught

Comment: Can anybody please help how to rid of this error?

Answer (score 1):

Use single quote for '$lookup' or escape it "\$lookup", or PHP will treat it as a variable, which is undefined/empty

Comment: ,you are correct.I was getting same issue but after escape character its working fine. thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is working with use of toArray();

error_reporting(1); 
    $collection = $this->mongo->your_db->admin;

```
    $ops = array(

        array(
            '$lookup' => array(
                "from" => "users",
                "localField" => "id",
                "foreignField" => "user_id",
                "as" => "inventory_docs"
            )
        )

    );
    $results = $collection->aggregate($ops)->toArray();
    echo "<pre>";    print_r($results);exit;
```